# Estimating Actual Ranking Amongst Other Quiz Takers

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, monte-carlo, survey

## Problem

The New York Times has a multiple choice "quiz" to evaluate their readers' understanding of recent news. They normally have a feature that reports your performance compared to other readers, i.e., what percentage of readers answered less questions correctly. This week it reported 0%, which seemed odd considering my score (9/11).

For each question, they report the success rate (what percentage of readers got it correct) and number of readers that answered that question. To check if there was a bug in the reporting (i.e., that the minimum score was 9/11) and estimate my actual performance, I ran (what I think are) Monte Carlo simulations.

Simulations were run by:

1. creating sample survey results. Concretely this means generating 74,563 possible reader responses using the success rate provided for each question
2. calculating the worst performance and my rank across each of these sample survey results. Below is the python code used to run the simulations, with questions embedded in near relevant sections (repeated in the following section for clarity).

```
from tqdm import tqdm
from random import random as rand
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

# Data
QUESTION_PERCENTAGE_POP = [(0.71,76879),(0.73,76302),(0.59,76038),(0.94,75523),(0.84,75303),(0.8,74563),(0.92,74387),(0.53,74159),(0.85,73857),(0.9,73527),(0.81,73549)]
QUESTION_SUCESSRATES, QUESTION_POPS = zip(*QUESTION_PERCENTAGE_POP)
POPULATION_THAT_COMPLETED_THE_SURVEY = min(QUESTION_POPS)
MY_SCORE = 9

def simulate_survey():
    pop_score_results = [sum([rand() < question_sr for question_sr in QUESTION_SUCESSRATES]) for individual in range(POPULATION_THAT_COMPLETED_THE_SURVEY)]
    percentage_better = sum([1 for score in pop_score_results if score < MY_SCORE])/POPULATION_THAT_COMPLETED_THE_SURVEY
    worst_score = min(pop_score_results)
    return pop_score_results, percentage_better, worst_score

if __name__ == "__main__":


    # Trial Settings and Results
    # QUESTION: How many trials are significant?
    NUM_TRIALS = 10000
    all_results = []
    worst_scores = []
    our_rank = []
    NUM_PROCESSES=32
    start_time = time.time()
    
    
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(NUM_PROCESSES)
    all_results, our_rank, worst_scores = zip(*pool.starmap(simulate_survey, [() for _ in range(NUM_TRIALS)] ))

    # QUESTION: How to pose the hypothesis
    # QUESTION: How to measure significance
    end_time = time.time()
    print("{} simulations took {} seconds".format(NUM_TRIALS, end_time-start_time))
    print(sum([score >=MY_SCORE for score in worst_scores]))
    print(np.mean(our_rank),np.std(our_rank))
    plt.hist(worst_scores)
    plt.show()
    plt.hist(our_rank)
    plt.show()
```

Running the code, it doesn't appear possible for the minimum score to be lower than 4.0 (over 10,000 trials) meaning that 0% is probably a bug. My actual performance seems to be closer to around 43% (mean) +- 0.18% (std)

** Note **

Some assumptions were made:

1. That we should not count partially completed surveys
2. That the success rate for partially completed surveys was the same as fully completed surveys

This is why 74,563 is used as the number of participants rather than the number per question.

## Questions

1. Does this approach make sense to figure out if 1) there was a bug (that the minimum score was 9 or higher) 2) my actual performance (percentage of readers with a lower score)
2. How many trials would I need to run get significant results?
3. How can I calculate confidence intervals?

I appreciate any feedback or comments, this is not something I've done before so it may be a little wonky.

Comment: Where in your simulation do you account for the likely (extremely large) positive correlation among responses?

Comment: Hmm, that's a good point that scores probably will cluster.I'm not sure how to implement that. One thing that comes to mind is assuming the score distribution is multimodal, but that seems like something I don't have enough information to select hyperparameters for. Any ideas or references on ways to account for positive correlation between scores?

Comment: What are good measures of correlation in this context? With such a metric I could limit samples to those that respect this constraint and sweep across it to see the impact

Comment: I would account for it by working backwards: is there any correlation pattern that could produce the score you got?  That's a nice little math problem, readily solved, whose answer might be more informative than any amount of simulation based on any assumptions.

Comment: Produce the score I got, or be able to recreate the distribution of score?  If I understand correctly you're suggesting modelling how to generate the data?